# Symfony Process npm install. Works in CLI doesn't work with HTTP

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, npm, command-line-interface

I have stumbled upon a very weird issue and I sincerely hope that you can explain to me why.

*Disclaimer: I know this is a bad idea, this isn't a real-life scenario but just a quirk I stumbled upon and I am curious to find out why this happens.*

Consider this piece of code:

```
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('node -v');
$process->mustRun();
echo $process->getOutput();

$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('npm install');
$process->mustRun();
echo $process->getOutput();
```

If I run this piece of code as: *php filename.php* it works as expected.
If I run this piece of code as part of a HTTP request (served by nginx), the first command returns the node version as expected while the second one raise an exception:

```
(1/1) ProcessFailedException
The command "npm install" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /Users/mrx/Documents/www/myCoolProject/

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
env: node: No such file or directory
```

Same exact thing happens with yarn.

It seems like NODE sets up some settings for NPM if the CLI is detected but I cannot seem to find any literature on this.
I know it's a bit far-fetched and not exactly a PHP related issue but I am really curious for an explanation.

FAQs:

- NPM/YARN are correctly installed and works as expected
- Above code works as expected in the CLI of php

Comment: You can use `which npm` to find out in which path these binaries are located. You can then compare if the `$PATH` variable in the CLI (using `echo $PATH` in a shell) with the value in the web context (it's part of the `$_SERVER` array). I guess these values will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Exit 127 looks like an out-of-memory issue, npm installs costs a lot of RAM and maybe that exceeds your Nginx or Apache PHP processes limits.